# Disable Log out short key mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Basically I'm playing a game (World of Warcraft) where a need lots of hotkeys available.

WoW disabled basic OS commands, which allows to use command key as a modifier, but I can't use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. It's not getting disabled by the game and still prompts the log-out window.

I tried researching the issue but didn't find anything. There is a `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` preference file, but it seems there is nothing there concerned with log-out.

Answer (score 2):

Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) and save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then press the ReloadXML button and tick the checkbox for the setting.

`__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L` would map shift-command-Q to shift-command-F19.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. The application has since been renamed to Karabiner, rest is the same (except the setting shows up as "test")

Answer (score 1):

Install a key mapping utility, and remap Command-Shift-Q to something else (or to nothing).

For example, [BetterTouchTool](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32953/bettertouchtool) should be able to help you with that (I'm sure there are other keyboard mappers out there as well).

Comment: I've tried BetterTouchTool. When entering a shortcut to remap it stops and logout window pops. It can record things like Command+Q and others, but not logout :/

Comment: Well isn't that a PITA. :(

Comment: I had a similar need for screen sharing with Jump Desktop (and I suspect likewise with Screen Sharing): a reflexive shift-command-q to log the user out on the remote machine causes you to log yourself off of your own machine.

I found that, though Keyboard Maestro can catch command-shift-q and (for example) call for a system beep instead of logging the user out, the override does *not* work when screen sharing with Jump Desktop.

@user495470’s suggestion to use Karabiner solved the problem.

Comment: As of Mojave, BetterTouchTool allows you to capture system shortcuts like Ctrl+Cmd+Q or Cmd+Shift+Q. I don't even have to attach an action, which means you can just no-op any key combination you like.